# WordPress - Gravity Forms - Create field dynamically

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Trying to create new fields for my form dynamically, as I'm getting json from 3rd party API. Based on this json, I need a number of fields added to my form - not fixed number. So, I'm doing this, hooking it onto `gform_pre_render`:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_process', 'create_products_gforms' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render', 'create_products_gforms' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'create_products_gforms' );
function create_products_gforms( $form ) {

    $helper = new NSHelper();
    $state_name = $_POST['input_7'] ?? '';

    $code_value = $helper->get_state_code_by_name( $state_name );

    // Only fetch products if current form id is 33, state code is defined
    // and if there are products for this state.

    if ( $form['id'] != 33 || !$code_value ) {
       return $form;
    }

    // Get product list from NetSuit API based on state code
    $products_json_data = get_products_data( $code_value );

    $products = json_decode( json_decode( $products_json_data ) );

    $new_field_id = 0;
    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if( $field->id > $new_field_id ) {
            $new_field_id = $field->id;
        }
    }

    $new_field_id++;

    foreach ( $products as $product_object ) {
        // Prepare field properties
        $props = array(
            'id'        => $new_field_id,
            'type'      => 'singleproduct',
            'label'     => $product_object->onlinedisplayname,
            'basePrice' => floatval( $product_object->price ),
            'enableCalculation' => true
        );

        // Create new gravity forms field and add it to the form object
        $nf = GF_Fields::create( $props );

        // Hack - insert into array at specific position
        // Needed to display product fields before other fields
        // in the form
        array_splice( $form['fields'], 11, 0, array($nf) );

        $new_field_id++;
    }

    GFAPI::update_form( $form );

    $form['dynamic_fields_ids'] = $added_fields_ids;

    return $form;
}
```

This works, ie, it shows fields properly on the frontend. Now, the issue with this is that, once form is submitted, all the fields except these dynamically added ones are in the submission. But these are not. I  assumed this has to do that these fields aren't registered in the form, so I also tried `GFAPI::update_form( $form );`, but that didn't help with submission part, though it udpates my form with new fields in the backend too.

Any ideas?

Comment: One thing to note is that fields temporarily added to the form (not saved in the db)  should also set the `formId` property at creation. Adding the field to the `$form['fields']` array is not enough. Without it, GF cannot 'see' the submitted data even though it exists in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your use-case, Milos, I would suggest using the gform_form_post_get_meta filter:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_form_post_get_meta/

This will fire every time the form is fetched from the database and the most sure-fire way of guaranteeing your fields will be present.

If you prefer to be more surgical and stick with the gform_pre_render approach, you'll want to apply the same function on a couple other filters:

`gform_pre_process`
`gform_admin_pre_render`

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've updated code in my question., as the code still doesn't update entry for some reason. However, I do get following for my newly created fields: Notice: Undefined index: 47.3 in /public/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/includes/fields/class-gf-field-singleproduct.php on line 66

Comment: Also, please note that I don't really want to save new fields for the form, to use it another time. I want to create fields, put it in the form just for the sake of this current entry being created, then remove them from the form. So, I don't need permanent fields in the form, just temporary ones.

Comment: How are you planning on viewing this entry data? Without the fields in place, GF won't know what to show in the admin.

Comment: What do you mean? If there's no field in the admin, it won't show in the entries list? That sounds ridiculous, to be honest. I was planning on creating fields, update form data, update form in the backend, save entry, remove newly added fields from the backend.

Comment: also, regardless of that, as I said, code above still doesn't work, even though I have added `GFAPI::update_form( $form );`.

Comment: I wouldn't use GFAPI::update_form() method here since dynamic fields are not intended to be permanent for all entries, only the entry for which that version of the form was submitted. My suggestion would be to store the version of the form meta for which an entry was submitted in the entry meta. Then use the `gform_form_post_get_meta` filter (or `gform_admin_pre_render`) to modify the form object based on the current entry being viewed.

Comment: David, thanks for your suggestion. I don't really understand how that would go. Mind showing this with a bit of code?

Comment: Wish I had the time, my friend, but I'm swamped. Hopefully someone else will come along and be able to provide some actual code examples. If not, feel free to ping me again in the future.